# Get schedules of particular date from date ranges with MDX query

Tags: ssas, mdx, between, dimensional-modeling

I already posted this problem many times, but unfortunately nobody could understand, I m sorry for my poor english :(
I reformulate ...

I have following fact table
[image]

I want to get records that match with a particular date and day of week (JOUR) in all dates range (DATE_DEB, DATE_FIN)

I can do that in SQL like this:

```
SELECT  DATE_DEB, 
DATE_FIN,
ID_HOR,
to_char(HR_DEB,'hh24:mi:ss') as HR_DEB,
to_char(HR_FIN,'hh24:mi:ss') as HR_FIN,
JOUR
FROM  GRP_HOR HOR, GRP
WHERE GRP.ID_ACTIV_GRP = HOR.ID_ACTIV_GRP
AND TO_DATE('1998-01-08', 'YYYY-MM-DD') between DATE_DEB and DATE_FIN
AND 1 + TRUNC(TO_DATE('1998-01-08', 'YYYY-MM-DD')) - TRUNC(TO_DATE('1998-01-08', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'IW') = JOUR
```

So, I'll get 29 records (see below) which included in each range and match with the day of week (JOUR ), after that I want to enlarge them by hours (HR_DEB, HR_FIN).

The problem is, what's how the best way to do this ?

- Create 2 date dimension and link them with DATE_DEB, DATE_FIN.
- Create 2 Time dimension and link them with HR_DEB, HR_FIN.

How can I implement the between SQL clause in MDX ? Or geater than or Less than ?

Thank you in advance.

OUTPUT :
[image]

Comment: (upped) interesting question

Answer (score 1):

To specify a range of dates in `MDX` you just use the colon operator `:`

Here is the documentation on `MSDN`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/mdx/range-mdx?view=sql-server-2017

This is the example they give:

```
With Member [Measures].[Freight Per Customer] as  
 (  
     [Measures].[Internet Freight Cost]  
     /   
     [Measures].[Customer Count]  
)  
SELECT   
    {[Ship Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[2004]&[1] : [Ship Date].[Calendar].[Month].&[2004]&[3]} ON 0,  
    [Product].[Category].[Category].Members ON 1  
FROM  
    [Adventure Works]  
WHERE  
    ([Measures].[Freight Per Customer])
```

Comment: I was finally able to implement a Many-To-Many relation via intermediate bridge for dates and times dimensions, the build time of the cube has increased little (15 min) but it's perfect for me, thank you very much guys !